# Error sending email in Talend Open Studio

Tags: java, email, talend

In Talend Open Studio using the tSendMail component, its correctly configured, but sometimes when I press Run, it shows an authentication error and othertimes it works perfectly.

[Config to the tSendMail Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PWJl.png)

this is the message when it runs ok

```
    Starting job ProbarConexiones at 17:14 16/02/2022.
    [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3990
    [statistics] connected
    [statistics] disconnected

Job ProbarConexiones ended at 17:14 16/02/2022. [exit code=0]
```

then this is the message when it fails

```
Starting job ProbarConexiones at 17:36 16/02/2022.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3671
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tSendMail_3 (ProbarConexiones)
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at proyectogeneralv2.probarconexiones_0_1.ProbarConexiones.tSendMail_3Process(ProbarConexiones.java:433)
    at proyectogeneralv2.probarconexiones_0_1.ProbarConexiones.runJobInTOS(ProbarConexiones.java:716)
    at proyectogeneralv2.probarconexiones_0_1.ProbarConexiones.main(ProbarConexiones.java:566)
[statistics] disconnected

Job ProbarConexiones ended at 17:36 16/02/2022. [exit code=1]
```

any idea what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Had to do these next steps:

1. Update the jar from 1.4.0 to 1.4.7 of the tSendMail component in the module view
2. Used this parameter `-Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2` in the preferences/Talend/RunDebug window

And now it works perfectly.

Comment: thank you for this
would be nice to get a guide to update module jars as well
finding anything talend-related is impossible 
https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/studio-user-guide/installing-external-modules-from-within-studio